# GtkD on Linux - Segmentation Fault error runnig "HelloWorld"

Tags: linux, gtkd

I am trying to compile and run a "Hello World" GtkD application on Linux. I followed this guide:

https://forum.gtkd.org/groups/GtkD/thread/1122/

Installed dmd compiler and gtkd3 with:

```
sudo snap install --classic dmd
sudo apt-get install libgtkd-3-dev
```

Compiled with:

```
rdmd -I/usr/include/d/gtkd-3/ -L-lgtkd-3 -L-ldl hello.d
```

I can compile (and link) successfully, however, when I run the application, I am getting a *Segmentation fault* error and no window shows.

I tried both on Ubuntu Mate 22.04 and on Linux Fossa Dog (based on Ubuntu 20.04).

What am I doing wrong?